# Run time error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am writing a program that is a simulation to a store. The problem is that when I try to get the total it only gives me the total for the last item I bought and not for all the items purchased. What am I doing wrong and what can I fix?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Invoice {

public static String partNum;
public String description;
public int quantity;
public double price;


    public String part_description(String parts){
                partNum=parts;

                if(parts.equals("10")){
                    description="This is a large metal hammer, $20";price=20;}
                else if(parts.equals("15")){description="This is a small plastic hammer, $5";price= 5;}
                else if(parts.equals("20")){description="This is a medium wooden hammer, $10";price=10;}
                else if(parts.equals("25")){description="This is a bucket of paint, $25";price=25;}
                else{description="No such part number exists.";}
                return description; 
    }
    public void setquantity(int amount){
        quantity=amount;

    }
    public int getquantity(){

        return quantity;
    }
    public void setprice(double cost){
        price=cost;
        if(cost<0){cost=0;}

    }
    public double getprice(){
        return price;
    }
    public double getInvoiceAmount(double total){
        total=total+(quantity*price);
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s1= new Scanner(System.in);
        Invoice invoiceObject= new Invoice();
        boolean ask=true;
        while(ask==true){


        System.out.println("Chose one of the fallowing part numbers: 10, 15, 20, 25");

         partNum=s1.nextLine();

        System.out.println(invoiceObject.part_description(partNum));

        System.out.printf("\nHow many #%s would you like to get: ", partNum);
        int numOf=s1.nextInt();
        invoiceObject.setquantity(numOf);



        System.out.println("would you like to keep shopping? chose true or false");
        ask=s1.nextBoolean();
        partNum=s1.nextLine();


        }



        System.out.println("Your total price will be:$ "+invoiceObject.getInvoiceAmount(0));




}}
```

Comment: This is a logical error...not a run time error.

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually adding up the total price anywhere.  You need to have a variable such as totalSum.  You want to set it at 0 before user starts doing anything.  Then you want to increment the prices.

```
//pseudo code.
totalSum = totalSum + (quantity*price)

//at the end
print(totalSum)
```

Comment: Thats what I did in getInvoiceAmount I wrote total=total+(quantity*price);

Comment: Yes, but you only pass in "0"....what do you think you should pass instead?  And should you just call it once?  What if you're adding to the total multiple times, shouldn't you call it from somewhere else?